# Can 'About this tab' content be changed in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

0

I am creating a app for Microsoft Teams. I am trying to create a tab using microsoft graph post api.

`/teams/${teamId}/channels/${channelId}/tabs` payload is an object with following params:

```
{
   displayName: 'My Tab'
   'teamsApp@odata.bind': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.web',
   configuration: {…},
};
```

Once the tab is created, We can click on the dropdown button which opens up a menu as below:
[image]

When we click on the 'About this tab' menu item, it opens up a pop dialog as below:

[image]

Question: My question is can I put my custom content in this dialog box. Is there any way I can change the content of it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to change the about content of a tab. We cannot add any custom contents in it.

Comment: Would be nice to add some more authority to this answer. Any reference? Experience?

Comment: Is this an answer or only some statement that you have the same problem?